# Upgraded MonoGame and now I can't get my shader to compile

Tags: opengl, shader, monogame

I upgraded my monogame to the latest version.  When building the shader in the pipeline tool at first I got the error Vertex shader 'SpriteVertexShader' must be SM 4.0 level 9.1 or higher! So I changed ps_2_0 to ps_4_0_level_9_1 but now I'm getting the error:

error X3004: undeclared identifier 'SecondPassTextureSampler'

Anybody have an idea on how to fix this issue?

```
#include "Macros.fxh"

texture Bitmap;

sampler2D FirstPassTexture = sampler_state{
    Texture = (Bitmap);
    MagFilter = Linear;
    MinFilter = Linear;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

sampler2D SecondPassTexture = sampler_state{
    Texture = (Bitmap);
    MagFilter = Linear;
    MinFilter = Linear;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

#define KERNEL_RADIUS 7
#define KERNEL_WIDTH (2*KERNEL_RADIUS + 1)

// Uniforms
BEGIN_CONSTANTS
    float kernel[KERNEL_WIDTH];
    float2 offsets[KERNEL_WIDTH];

MATRIX_CONSTANTS
    float4x4 MatrixTransform    _vs(c0) _cb(c0);
END_CONSTANTS

struct VSOutput
{
    float4 position     : SV_Position;
    float4 color        : COLOR0;
    float2 texCoord     : TEXCOORD0;
};

VSOutput SpriteVertexShader(    float4 position : SV_Position,
                                float4 color    : COLOR0,
                                float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0)
{
    VSOutput output;
    output.position = mul(position, MatrixTransform);
    output.color = color;
    output.texCoord = texCoord;
    return output;
}

float4 gaussH(VSOutput input): SV_Target0
{
    float4 color = float4(0,0,0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < KERNEL_WIDTH; ++i)
        color += SAMPLE_TEXTURE(SecondPassTexture, (input.texCoord + float2(offsets[i].x, 0.0) )) * kernel[i];
    return color * input.color;
}

float4 gaussV(VSOutput input): SV_Target0
{
    float4 color = float4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < KERNEL_WIDTH; ++i)
        color += SAMPLE_TEXTURE(SecondPassTexture, (input.texCoord + float2(0.0, offsets[i].y) )) * kernel[i];
    return color * input.color;
}

float4 gaussVGlow(VSOutput input): SV_Target0
{
    float4 color = float4(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < KERNEL_WIDTH; ++i)
    {
        float alpha = SAMPLE_TEXTURE(SecondPassTexture, (input.texCoord + float2(0.0, offsets[i].y) )).a * kernel[i];
        color.a += alpha;
    }
    // This will make stripes on top of the glow
    /*
    float m = smoothstep(0.45, 0.55, 0.5*cos(25.0*atan2(input.texCoord.y-0.5, input.texCoord.x-0.5))+0.5) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    color.a *= m;
    */
    color.a = pow(color.a, 0.5);
    color.rgb *= color.a; // Yeah, you have to pre multiply your alpha -- either that or render with premultiply option
    return color * input.color;
}

technique Blur {
    pass p0 {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0_level_9_1 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 gaussH();
    }
    pass p1 {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0_level_9_1 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 gaussV();
    }
    pass p1Glow {
        VertexShader = compile vs_4_0_level_9_1 SpriteVertexShader();
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 gaussVGlow();
    }
}
```

Macros.fxh is: http://pastebin.com/y51kFfii

Comment: Your shader doesn't look like GLSL; what is `technique` and `pass`? Also, `SecondPassTextureSampler` doesn't appear in the shader; are you sure it's your shader failing and not your C# code?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.
techinque and pass are from the XNA Macros that i linked.  SecondPassTextureSampler get's created automatically I think.  I'm not even running C# code, just the Monogame pipeline tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Monogame Forum:
You get an error because you use the macro SAMPLE_TEXTURE for sampling, but do not use the macro DECLARE_TEXTURE for declaring the texture.
If you want to use the macros in Macros.fxh then the texture needs to be named SecondPassTexture and the sampler needs to be named SecondPassTextureSampler. (Do not change the line where SAMPLE_TEXTURE is called.)

If you look at the macro (_Macro.fxh, line 31), the code

SAMPLE_TEXTURE(SecondPassTexture, (input.texCoord + float2(0.0, offsets[i].y) ))
expands to

SecondPassTexture.Sample(SecondPassTextureSampler, (input.texCoord + float2(0.0, offsets[i].y) ))
But in your case (original post) it should be

Bitmap.Sample(SecondPassTexture, (input.texCoord + float2(0.0, offsets[i].y) ))
Here is a simpler solution, you can try:
Just replace all SAMPLE_TEXTURE with tex2D. (Leave the samplers as in the original post.)

Comment: As an additional note, I was having additional issues and I found that installing MonoGame 3.5 overtop of my previous install was bad and uninstalling and reinstalling fixed some issues.